# Simple query from Dataflow to BigQuerySource throws exception

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to write a simple Dataflow job that utilizes the `query` parameter within the `BigQuerySource` class.

In simplest terms, I can access a BigQuery table using the `BigQuerySource` class, and then filter against it. I cannot query / filter directly against the BigQuery table using the `BigQuerySource`.

Here's some code. Filtering in-line, within my Dataflow pipeline, works fine:

```
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--output', required=True)
known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(None)    
p = beam.Pipeline(argv=pipeline_args)

source = 'bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare'
rows = p | 'read'>>beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(source))
f = rows | 'filter' >> beam.Map(lambda row: 1 if (row['word_count'] > 1) else 0) 

f | 'write' >> beam.io.WriteToText(known_args.output)    
p.run()
```

Replacing that middle stanza with a single line query gives an error.

```
f = p | 'read' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource('SELECT 1 FROM ' \
    + 'bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare where word_count > 1'))
```

The error returned looks like a syntax error.

```
(a29eabc394a38f62): Workflow failed. Causes: 
(a29eabc394a38cfa): S04:read+write/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles+write/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+write/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+write/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+write/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write failed.,
(fb6d0643d7f13886): BigQuery execution failed., 
(fb6d0643d7f13b03): Error:  Message: Encountered " "-" "- "" at line 1, column 59. Was expecting: <EOF>
```

Do I need to escape the `-` characters in the BigQuery project name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In BigQuery Legacy SQL - you should escape whole table reference with `[` and `]`
For Standard SQL you should use [`back-ticks`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/lexical) for the same reason

See also [Escaping reserved keywords and invalid identifiers](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#escaping_reserved_keywords_and_invalid_identifiers)

Comment: "The whole table reference" means the project, dataset and table? When trying that I'm told that it's an invalid table, i.e. `Message: Invalid table name: \`bigquery-public-data:samples.shakespeare\``

Comment: check also - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql#project-qualified_table_names - in standard sql you should replace `:` with `.`

Comment: Perfect - replacing the `:` with a `.` solved this for me. Thank you!